# Getting a relative path for current project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a relative path, for example: `C:\somedirectory\someproject\someproject.Business\somefolder\`

I tried `Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath)`. But it returns the DevServer's folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have separated your solution in different projects and that you have at least:

- A business layer
- Web application

From the information above, it would seem that you're trying to access a folder located in the business layer. But you're probably executing the code from the web server application and this is why none of the answers before have worked.

If it is a certain file that you're trying to access, I would suggest that you change the files/folders build action in visual studio. This will automatically copy the files to the right context in which the application is running.
[image]

> The BuildAction property indicates what Visual Studio does with a file when a build is executed. BuildAction can have one of several values:
>
> **None** - The file is not included in the project output group and is not compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains documentation, such as a Readme file.
>
> **Compile** - The file is compiled into the build output. This setting is used for code files.
>
> **Content** - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an .htm or other kind of Web file.
>
> **Embedded Resource** - This file is embedded in the main project build output as a DLL or executable. It is typically used for resource files.

You can read more information about build action on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for concise explanation of the question, as well as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Server.Mappath(string path);
```

Comment: No, I already use mappath to get the physical path from the relative path, but it resolves to solution root.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) Method

The method returns a string that contains the path of the current working directory, and does not end with a backslash ().